# Executing awk in Python shell

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a `shell` command which parses a certain content and gives the required output. I need to implement this in python but the shell command has a new line character `"\n"` which is not getting getting executed when run through python command.

Of the many lines in the output log, the required line looks like - `configurationFile=/app/log/conf/the_jvm_name.4021.logback.xml`

I would only need **the_jvm_name** from the above. The syntax will always be the same. The shell command works fine.

Shell Command -

```
ps -ef | grep 12345 | tr " " "\n" | grep logback.configurationFile | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'| cut -d. -f1
```

Python (escaped all the required double quotes) -

```
import subprocess
pid_arr = "12345"
sh_command = "ps -ef | grep "+pid_arr+" | tr \" \" \"\n\" | grep configurationFile | awk -F \"/\" '{print $NF}' | cut -d. -f1"
outpt = subprocess.Popen(sh_command , shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
```

With python, I'm not getting the desired output. It just prints configurationFile as it is in the command. 
what am I missing here. Any other better way for getting this details?

Comment: The easiest way would be to split and parse the output from `subprocess` using python  rather than relying on `grep` + `tr`  + `grep` + `awk`

Comment: I've tried that but it's breaking off the output. Can we use regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a regex substitution in Python:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-ef"])
for line in output.splitlines():
  if re.search("12345", line):
    output = re.sub(r".*configurationFile=.*/([^.]+).*", r"\1", line)
```

This captures the part after the last `/` in the configuration file path, up to the next `.`.

You could make it slightly more robust by checking only the second column (the PID) for `12345`, either by splitting each line on white space:

```
cols = re.split("\s+", line) 
if len(cols) > 1 and cols[1] == "12345":
```

or by using a better regex, like:

```
if re.match(r"\S+\s+12345\s", line):
```

Note that you could also shorten your pipe considerable by just doing something like:

```
ps -ef | sed -nE '/12345/ { s/.*configurationFile=.*\/([^.]*).*/\1/; p }'
```

Comment: Tom, the number 12345 is dynamic, it keeps changing based on a output which i get from an other command. it's a process ID.  i'll check this one. tq!

Comment: @sdgd in that case you can build the regex dynamically, or just use split the lines into columns and compare directly (I updated the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your shell command works, but it has to deal with too many lines of output and too many fields per line. An easier solution is to tell the `ps` command to just give you 1 line and on that line, just one field that you care about. For example, on my system:

```
ps -o cmd h 979
```

will output:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
```

The `-o cmd` flag will output only the *CMD* column of the output, while the `h` parameter represents a command to tell `ps` to omit the header. Finally, the `979` is the process ID, which tells `ps` to output information just for this process.

This output is not exactly what you have in your problem, but similar enough. Once we limited the output, we eliminate the need for other commands such as `grep`, `awk`, ... At this point, we can use regular expression to extract what we want:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import subprocess

pid = '979'
command = ['ps', '-o', 'cmd', 'h', pid]
output = subprocess.check_output(command)

pattern = re.compile(r"""
    config-file=  # Literal string search
    .+\/          # Everything up to the last forward slash
    ([^.]+)       # Non-dot chars, this is what we want
""", re.VERBOSE)

matched = pattern.search(output)

if matched:
    print(matched.group(1))
```

## Notes

- For the regular expression, I am using a verbose form, allowing me to use comment to annotate my pattern. I like this way as regular expression can be difficult to read
- On your system, please adjust the *"configuration-file"* part to work with your output.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Hai. In the regex, shouldn't we also write the ending part of it? More like left and right boundries ? `configurationFile=/app/log/conf/the_jvm_name.4021.logback.xml` .. i would be needing between `configurationFile=/app/log/conf` and `.4021.logback.xml` because the number 4021 is also dynamic. so the end should be from `.` to `xml`

Comment: We could, but if this works, then why should we do more?